# Who is trying to use the Stealth Mode as reported in Console

Tags: network, dns, firewall

I found following in my Console on MBA 10.13

```
Stealth Mode connection attempt to UDP 192.168.0.12:52734 from 8.8.8.8:53    
Stealth Mode connection attempt to UDP 192.168.0.12:57880 from 8.8.8.8:53    
Stealth Mode connection attempt to UDP 192.168.0.12:51017 from 8.8.8.8:53
```

I know the 8.8.8.8 is Google DNS server that I use.

The 192.168.0.12 is my en0 IP.

The Host file looks like this

Host Database

```
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.

127.0.0.1   localhost

255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost 
fe80::1%lo0 localhost
```

I also found one of the IP 192.168.0.12:52734 actualy leads to a weird page. http://foro.euskaltel.com/Thread-Test-de-Velocidad-Internet?page=88

Comment: If your *internal* IP points to an outside host/domain, there is something going on with *your* machine.  It could be in your hosts file, you could be have your own DNS server up and running or some other service that is resolving that IP/port to that particular page.

Comment: The title is three questions. That seems a little broad for someone who is a veteran user. Can you pick one if you want answers other than your self answer (which is greatly appreciated if you have sussed it all out now)

Comment: @bmike  ok fixed, those are the same questions, (Who or What) = Why ! and the Post is very detailed with information.

Comment: I really like that edit. Thanks for being open to a suggestion.  Hopefully it reverses the one vote deficit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The request came from 8.8.8.8:53 which is Google's Public Domain Name Server to my IP 192.xxx.xx

Google is probably responding to a request from my computer and my computer thinks the response is stealth connection attempt.